# Python, Magic Methods: cannot understand the task

Tags: python, addition

I'm learning python
I should make a task but i cannot understand it :)
How the "mississippi" has to be passed to the magic method? I see that only list of integers is passed to the Counter.

**Description**
You have to overload the addition operator in Counter class. Use the **add**() magic method to overload the addition.

For example, in case of a + b, a object should have **add**() which accepts b as a second parameter (self goes first).

In this case, Counter object accepts a list from int as a parameter. Object to summarize with will be a str object. The result should be a list of strings which have the following pattern: 1 test - one object from list and str separated by the whitespace.

**Default code:**

```
from typing import List


class Counter:
    def __init__(self, values: List[int]):
        self.values = values
    # TODO: add your code here
```

**Example**

```
>>> Counter([1, 2, 3]) + "mississippi"

["1 mississippi", "2 mississippi" , "3 mississippi"]
```

Comment: To overload the addition operator in the Counter class, define the __add__ magic method. This method takes a string as its second parameter. Iterate through the list of integers and concatenate each integer value with the provided string. Return a list of strings with this pattern. This approach allows you to concatenate each integer value from the list with the given string, fulfilling the task requirements.

Comment: {

from typing import List

class Counter:
    def __init__(self, values: List[int]):
        self.values = values
    
    def __add__(self, string: str) -> List[str]:
        return [f"{value} {string}" for value in self.values]

# Example usage:
counter = Counter([1, 2, 3])
result = counter + "mississippi"
print(result)  # Output: ['1 mississippi', '2 mississippi', '3 mississippi'] 

}

Comment: @sai Override, not overload. Python doesn't have function overloading.

Comment: Strictly, an override of \_\_add__ should return an instance of the class in which it is implemented. The task you've been set is an abuse of this paradigm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `__add__` function, you follow a design where the method dynamically accepts the second operand during the operation. This method gives you much more flexibility

So this is a standard implementation:

```
from typing import List

class Counter:
    def __init__(self, values: List[int]):
        self.values = values

    def __add__(self, other: str) -> List[str]:
        # Create a list of strings by combining each number from self.values with the string 'other'
        return [f"{value} {other}" for value in self.values]

# Example usage:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    counter = Counter([1, 2, 3])
    result = counter + "mississippi"
    print(result)
```

output: `["1 mississippi", "2 mississippi", "3 mississippi"]`

Answer (score 0):

This is your question:

> How the "mississippi" has to be passed to the magic method?

The problem description says:

> in case of `a + b`, `a` object should have `__add__()` which accepts `b` as a second parameter (`self` goes first)

This tells you that "mississippi" is passed as the `b` parameter to `__add__`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Bob is correct. You need to implement the `__add__` method.
You can read an explanation of python magic methods [here](https://realpython.com/python-magic-methods/).

What you want is essentially this:

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, values: List[int]):
        self.values = values

    def __add__(self, new_str):
        return [str(value) + " " + new_str for value in self.values]
```

You can also use a [formatted string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings):

```
def __add__(self, new_str):
        return [f'{value} {new_str}' for value in self.values]
```

Answer (score 0):

An override of __add__ should return self.

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, values: list[int]):
        self._values = values
        self._list = []
    def __add__(self, txt: str):
        self._list = [f"{v} {txt}" for v in self._values]
        return self
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return repr(self._list)
        
print(Counter([1,2,3]) + "mississippi")
```

**Output:**

```
['1 mississippi', '2 mississippi', '3 mississippi']
```